# Sorting Column in Pandas dataframe-Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, columnsorting

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| class_id | dims |
| --- | --- |
| 94369_GA_30122 | 95 |
| 27369_GA_30122 | 14 |
| 78369_CA_30122 | 27 |
| 30472_MN_55121 | 16 |

and the dataframe goes on... I want to sort my column class_id numerically ascending, that is itt must look like

| class_id | dims |
| --- | --- |
| 27369_GA_30122 | 14 |
| 30472_MN_55121 | 16 |
| 78369_CA_30122 | 27 |
| 94369_GA_30122 | 95 |

can anyone tell me how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should do the trick:

```
data = {"class_id": ["94369_GA_30122", "27369_GA_30122", "78369_CA_30122", "30472_MN_55121"],
        "dims": [95, 14, 27, 16]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = df.sort_values("class_id")

Out:
         class_id  dims
1  27369_GA_30122    14
3  30472_MN_55121    16
2  78369_CA_30122    27
0  94369_GA_30122    95
```

Edit:
You can also add these lines to only sort on the first set of numbers.

```
df["sorting"] = df["class_id"].str.split("_", n=1).str[0]    # Extracting only the first set of numbers
df = df.sort_values("sorting")
df = df.drop("sorting", axis=1)    # To drop the column again
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort the value by class_id :

```
df.sort_values(by=['class_id'])
```

If you want to sort the value by dims :

```
df.sort_values(by=['dims'])
```

Tf you want to sort based on both you can use :

```
df.sort_values(by=['class_id', 'dims'])
```

you can refer from this site -
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

Comment: I tried using this method `df.sort_values(by=['class_id'])` but it sorts class_id like 100000_WI_53929, 100004_IL_61364 and not like 1_NH_03275, 2_IL_61270

Comment: Then try to use **df.sort_values(by=['class_id', 'dims'])** it will sort based on value in both column